# Table cell prototype - outlets not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios6

I have cell prototype with custom class where I have outlets.

[image: Outlet connections]
[image: Custom class set in IB on cell prototype]

STRMEpisodeCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Show.h"

@interface STRMEpisodeCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) Show *show;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *showLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *episodeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *posterView;
@end
```

STRMEpisodeCell.m

```
#import "STRMEpisodeCell.h"

@interface STRMEpisodeCell ()

@end

@implementation STRMEpisodeCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)setShow:(TVDbShow *)show
{
    _show = show;
    self.showLabel.text = show.title;
}

@end
```

STRMViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.episodeTable.dataSource = self;
    [self.episodeTable registerClass:[STRMEpisodeCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"episode"];

    self.list = //loading data here;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    STRMEpisodeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"episode"];
    cell.show = self.list[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

When I set breakpoint on `cell.show = self.list[indexPath.item];` in `cell` it simply shows that all the outlets are nil.

Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: more IB screenshots - what is the top-level class and file's owner of your nib?

Comment: If you set this cell up in the storyboard, then you don't need to register the class (and I think when I've done that, it actually kept it from working properly, so try commenting that out). I'm not sure whether this will make a difference, but use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: instead of just dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:.

Comment: rdelmar: OMG thanks, it was the class registration, thank you sir! I am going to have it set in IB only then. Rewrite it into answer if you want, I will accept it later. I am using storyboards btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a table view cell that you set up in the storyboard, you shouldn't register the class, because that will keep the table view from getting the cell you set up in IB. I think you only want to register a class when you set up the cell entirely in code.

If, you make the cell in a xib file, and have a custom class, then you register the nib rather than the class.